# How can I automate running an init script when invoking a postgres DB using psql?

Tags: postgresql

psql (9.6.7, server 9.5.2) on linux

I have an init script... ~/sql.ini that I always want to run after connecting to a PG DB.  I can do this by typing "\i ~/sql.ini", but is there a way to do this on the command line (which I alias) ?

Answer (score 1):

Just put your commands in [~/.psqlrc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) file.

Comment: That did it.  Thanks pensnarik !

Answer (score 0):

Your alias should call

```
PSQLRC=~/sql.ini psql
```

That environment variable specifies the startup file that `psql` executes automatically.